# How to fire-up Java method from a Hook defined within mercurial.ini

Tags: java, python, mercurial

I'm newbie to both Mercurial and Python and I was trying to implement an extension and was wondering if it's possible to fire-up or execute a Java method if I defined an hook within mercurial.ini file.

Let's say I had a Java method:

### Java method

```
 public class Hello {

      public void doSomething(String str) {
          System.out.println("Hello World");
      }
 }
```

### Mercurial.ini

I know we can call a python function like this:

```
  precommit = python: d:\workspace\Hello.py:doSomething
```

but can we do something like similar by calling Java method:

```
  precommit = java: d:\workspace\Hello.java:doSomething
```

I tried doing above but didn't work for me!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible but not that simple. Mercurial doesn't know how to start Java or how to call methods in it.

The solution is to [create an executable JAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html) and then use this code:

```
precommit = java -jar YourJarFile.jar ...arguments...
```

as a hook (without a prefix, the hook is expected to be a system command).

Comment: I see, one more question do I need to wrap my method around `main(String... args)` ?

Comment: Also what if we wanted to run a particular method from a class say that we had 2 other method  
`doThisThing(int num)`and `doThatThing(double num)`  
how can we call a particular method, I mean can we do this:  
`precommit = java -jar d:\Hello.jar:doThisThing 10`

Comment: As I said, you need an executable JAR: That means a class with a static `main()` method. You must pass the method you want to call as command line argument and examine it in `main()` There are no shortcuts.

Comment: I thought there might be an alternative way to pass in param directly to class method instead of making the Jar executable and then pass those param from `main()` to respected methods. Ta